# 403 Forbidden nginx in path home/project/media2

Tags: http, nginx

I'm getting a 403 forbidden from nginx, but I've already added the permissions on the folder/files, being 755 for folder and 644 for files.
in this case I have already inserted autoindex on; autoindex_exact_size off; but the problem still continues, could anyone help me with this

Here's my nginx file

```
       location ~ ^/media2/detail/ {
       alias /home/sftpserver/projects/myproject/media2/detail;
       autoindex on;
       autoindex_exact_size off;
       location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js|xlsx|dat|mod|glp|Ink|out)$ {
                    expires 30d;
                }
     }
```

Here's my nginx access.log file

```
     154.39.13.17 - - [13/Apr/2018:10:44:55 -0300] "GET /media2/detail/execution_detail_252.xlsx/ HTTP/1.1" 403 192
     "https://subdomion.dominiom.com.br" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0;
     Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
     Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

Here's my nginx error.log file

```
2018/04/13 10:41:47 [error] 12737#0: *1 directory index of "/home/sftpserver/projects/myproject/media2" is forbidden, client: 169.39.13.127, server: subdomion.dominiom.com.br, request: "GET /media2/detail/execution_detail_251.xlsx/ HTTP/1.1", host: "subdomion.dominiom.com.br", referrer: "https://subdomion.dominiom.com.br"
```

If someone can help me, I will be enormously grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `alias` incorrectly. When used with a regular expression `location`, the entire URI should be captured and appended to the `alias` statement. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) for details.

But, you should not be using `alias` in this particular case, as `root` can be used instead.

For example:

```
location ~ ^/media2/detail/ {
    root /home/sftpserver/projects/myproject;
    ...
}
```